# How can I make a function treat a whole sentence like one parameter?

Tags: bash

How should I pass a sentence to function and make it behave like one parameter.

Example:

```
function Test ()
{
  echo $1 
}
body="This the test"
Test $body
```

I want output like this=> "This the test"  because of spaces it will print me Test only. What specific characters should i put to make whole sentence like one parameter. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Next time I recommend that you put your actual code in the question if you want to get useful answers quickly.  I've updated your question to reflect what you asked for in comments.

Answer (score 6):

Always quote all parameter substitutions.

```
function Test() {
  echo "$1"   # needs quoting
}
body='This the test'  # double quotes would also work in this case
Test "$body"  # needs quoting as well
```

Corrected and readable version of the code below:

```
logger() {
    local message="$1"
    local mode="$2"
    case "$mode" in
        0)
            echo "$message"
            ;;
        1)
            echo "$message" > "$LOG_FILE_DIRECTORY_PATH$LOG_FILE_NAME"
            echo
            ;;
    esac
}

logmsg=' This is log message '
logger "$logmsg" 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Quoting the arguments as you do in your question will work.

```
$ function ztest () { echo $1; }
$ ztest "This is a test"
This is a test
```

So, there's nothing else you need to do.

Edit: from comments, you have a `logger` function and want to pass it two arguments, a string and a "mode".  You would do this as follows:

```
logger "This is a test" 0
```

or, if the log message is in a variable,

```
logger "$logmessage" 0
```

Putting your variables inside " is rarely a bad idea in shell scripts.

Comment: Thanks my mistake was that i puted  param in "" like  "$1" i just removed it and it work

Comment: body="Test logger function" logger $body 0   will print only "Test"

Comment: @alper Sigh.  That's because you're not quoting the arguments.

Comment: Thanks very helpful!! i spend 2 hours for  it now undestood)))

Comment: @Philipp not for echo if it's just a single sentence

Comment: @Philipp ... good point ... it was still early in the morning for me.

Answer (score 1):

Use the special parameter which includes all positional parameters and quote it. If you quote the input argument as you show in your question, your existing function should have worked, though.

```
Test () { echo "$@"; }
```

Comment: @alper: please don't post long pieces of code in the comments, they're quite unreadable. Add them to your question instead.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys !!! work perfectly

```
logmsg=" This is log message "
logger "$logmsg" 0
logger ()
{
      # mode=$(echo ${@:${#@}} ) #last from parameters
     mode=${@: -1}
     [ $mode -eq 2 ]  && return
     B=`[ $mode -eq 0 ] && echo $1 `
     F=`echo $1 > $LOG_FILE_DIRECTORY_PATH$LOG_FILE_NAME `
     echo ${B:-$F}
}
```

Comment: Please format your code using four-space indenting, the `{}` button or Ctrl-K. Note that you can't call a function before it's defined. This probably should have been edited into the question, because it's not really an answer (but I'm not going to flag it as a non-answer).

Comment: That code has still many issues, especially with respect to quoting. I've edited my answer to include a corrected version.